# Detect a number in entity in IBM Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I need the user to input his flight number in order to fetch its details for him.
Is there any way to detect and store the flight number (3-4 digits + words) that he entered?
I know that I can create an entity in order to store some parts of the user inputs, but it seems like I have to hard-code values which I want to retrieve, which is not practical.
So, is there any option to make watson automatically detect a part of user input (not limited to numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your condition section you can put in the following.

```
input.text.matches('.*?[0-9]{3,4}.*?')
```

For your output area, go to advanced mode and do the following.

```
{
    "output": {
        "text": "You typed a 3-4 digit number. I stored it in Context variable 'found'"
    },
    "context": {
        "found": "<? input.text ?>"
    }
}
```

You can then query the context variable `found` in your code to do more complex actions on it.

---

Conversation has been updated since this answer. You can now use `input.text.extract()` instead of just `input.text`.

Like so:

```
"found": "<? input.text.extract('.*?([0-9]{3,4}).*?',1) ?>"
```